# Two datasets and two separate objectives: Is it okay to combine datasets to train for different classifications?

Tags: python, classification, clustering, k-means

Some background:

I'm currently working on a research project where we have a given training set of ~6k records of economic published papers from a different research group and a separately data-scraped set of ~267k records that we want to actually classify.

The initial goal of the project is to classify the scraped data into two categories. One of the features we use for this are the economic fields where the paper comes from, noted by JEL codes. JEL codes are categorized first by letter (A-Z) as [outlined here](https://www.aeaweb.org/jel/guide/jel.php), then split into a numerical subcategory.

The fields are given in the given training set, but we decided to shift into a different method of classification that deviates from how the original authors have using JEL codes (which are economic journal codes that are tagged when a paper is published).

So my goal (or what I want to do) now, is to use a [k-means++ semi-supervised algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.00360.pdf) to cluster the records of each individual paper into approximately 17 to 20 different JEL categories possible, where the "supervised" data will come from papers that have JEL codes that are only from one JEL category or letter.

For example, a paper with A1, A21, and A2 will be labeled as 'A' by default, while a paper with A1, B1, and Z1 will be considered an unlabeled record since it has JEL codes with multiple letters.

After I have the fields, I wish to use these features for the binary classification later in the process, which I have already coded with the split train and larger 'test' mentioned above.

QUESTION:

So in implementing this, would it be incorrect to merge the two datasets solely for the clustering portion? I would like to have more data since the training dataset doesn't cover all of the different JEL categories that the test dataset has.

In theory, I feel like it wouldn't affect the second binary classification part, but I do understand that usually training and testing sets should remain separate.

[Edit]If I can't I plan to use the clustering algorithm to output centroids for the training set, then use some hyperparameter & distance to centroid to classify (although I've read that classifying with clustering isn't the best solution). Otherwise, I would use the centroids from the full dataset (combined) to classify the fields using hyperparameters & distance to the centroid. (like k-nearest neighbors.)

If anyone has other suggestions as to how I should approach this, it is also welcome!